# ¿no me imprime una imagen guardada en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

No se si mi codigo esta pobre o esta mal por lo que la imagen la guerde en blob o ¿es esta la forma?

```
<?php
    include("conexion/conexion.php");
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM noticias'); 
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
       echo "<div style='color:black' border='1'> \n"; 
        do{
          echo "<h1>".$row["titulo_noticia"]."</h1><br><img src=".$row["fotos_noticia"]."/><br><h2>".$row["subtitulo_noticia"]."</h2><br><p style='color:black'>".$row["descripcion_noticia"]."</p><br><label style='color:black'>".$row["autor_noticia"]."<br>".$row["fecha"]."</label></div> \n"; 
        }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); 
    } else { 
        echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: solo es en la Parte <img src="...."/>

Comment: 1- da detalles del problema, 2- como y cuando se presenta tu problema, 3- Cual deberia ser el resultado final.. eso ayudara a tener mas respuesta para tu situacion

Comment: 1-lo que quiero es imprimir es una imagen que esta guardada en la base de datos mysql y esta guardada en tipo blob. 2-mi error es que no me imoprime segun mi codigo, no se si ser blob el codigo varie mucho

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php
        include("conexion/conexion.php");
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM noticias'); 
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           echo "<div style='color:black' border='1'> \n"; 
            do{
              echo "<h1>".$row["titulo_noticia"]."</h1><br><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$row["fotos_noticia"]."'/><br><h2>".$row["subtitulo_noticia"]."</h2><br><p style='color:black'>".$row["descripcion_noticia"]."</p><br><label style='color:black'>".$row["autor_noticia"]."<br>".$row["fecha"]."</label></div> \n"; 
            }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); 
        } else { 
            echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: lo implemente pero hay un error de comillas estoy viendo donde es y ya te digo gracias

Comment: no te preocupes ya lo corregi puedes utilizarlo!

Comment: muchas gracias Bryro si funciono